# Does BOSS GT-1 have a stompbox mode and bank mode?

Tags: electric-guitar

Does the BOSS GT-1 have a stompbox mode and bank mode the way it is in Digitech RP 360XP?

Comment: The better place for this question is Roland themselves. They are very helpful through emails.

Answer (score 2):

The up and down buttons are assigned to next and previous patch by default on all patches, but can be reassigned, so three switches and one exp pedal per patch